# "I do not like either of the sisters." What does this sentence mean exactly?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

> I do not like either of the sisters.

What does this exactly mean?

A) I don’t like one of the two sisters (I dont know which one is that).

B) I don’t like one of the two sisters (I know which one is that but just didn’t mention).

C) I don’t like both sisters.

D) I like both sisters.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence C is closest, but putting it that way is ambiguous. Sentence C could mean "I don't like both sisters. I like only one of them."
Your original sentence is not ambiguous. To capture that meaning, you could say
"I like neither Mary nor Margaret."
You could also say "I dislike both sisters.", but that may indicate a stronger feeling than "do not like".

Comment: So can I say “I like neither of the sisters”? Is it gramatically correct?

Comment: Yes, that is grammatically correct, and captures the meaning of "I do not like either of the sisters.'